# Frontend not connected to Backend from Private IP on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a 3 individual Instance for my Project on AWS.

1. Frontend

   - Written on React.JS Language. This will communicate node Server through API.
2. Backend

   - Written On Node.JS Language. This Will Communicate MongoDB through Private IP of an Instance.
3. Database

   - Used MongoDB Database. Communicate Node Server(Instance) through Private IP.

Now My problem is that My React Server will not be able to Communicate Node Server Through its API by using Private IP of Node Instance. If I mentioned the public IP of Node Instance on React Code (File Where global variable is created for Accessing the API) then it will connect to Node and return the response.

If I mentioned the private IP instead of Public IP then Communication is not happened. 
I tried VPC, Public and private subnet, all are tested but not able to figure it out that what is the exactly reason by which my React will not be able to communicate node server through Private IP of Node instance.

Any AWS Expert here can guide me that what are the things I missed or I have to use. Any help is Really appreciated for that.

Comment: Log into instance where you are running React and try to reach the API with linux `curl` command using private IP. If this doesn't work and Node server sits in a different subnet then check subent NACLs whether they are not blocking the traffic (you can also check SGs but it sounds more like a problem with NACLs). Lastly, you should consider using S3 for static website hosting instead of running your own React server.

Comment: sorry to mention this things that curl works perfectly fine. On react server I use curl http:// url (private ip) it return response. But things not work on React code where react can call node server

Comment: @MatusDubravam Dear can you show me some light regarding the hosting of React Code on S3 instead of using seperate server. And really appreciate for your inputs

Comment: First you need to build your React app using `npm run build` command and then upload contents of `build` directory to your s3 bucket. On s3 bucket, you need to configure `static website hosting` and add a bucket policy that allows `s3:getObject` for everyone. Note that if you are planning to use custom domain with HTTPS then the name of the bucket must be the same as the name of your domain.

Comment: @MatusDubrava Dear I created the test site on AWS S3. My question is after testing I want to Down that site. But This is Continous Live. If I disable Web Hosting option on Static Website Hosting Popup then it will not accessible. And when I Enable again that site is live. How to like remove or completely shutdown that site?

Comment: If you want to completely get rid of it then you can delete the whole S3 bucket.

Comment: What about if we have to down the site for an hour?

Comment: Then you can remove bucket policy which allows access to the website.

Comment: @MatusDubrava Thanks a lot for giving me the input. Really appreciate for your kindness

Comment: @MatusDubrava Please suggest me how to use nginx on this. Like in this case, AWSCLI is installed on my machine. I have to just change on package.json code and when I deploy. Automatically It will reach to s3. So what about NGINX. I have to install nginx on my develoment machine and configure same as I deploy the code? Or this have some other technique/approach?

Comment: If you are using S3 static website hosting then there is no need to Nginx. S3 itself can be used as a webserver.

Comment: @MatusDubrava still If I would like to use nginx for routing and caching purpose then how I can proceed?